# Looking for guidance for Facebook Messenger's Webhook for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I would like to know if there is a way (using any server side calls) to automate the subscribing to Messenger Webhook for specific Facebook Page. The user gives us access and we have the page's access token but we don't know how to make the subscription to page's messenger's events programmatically. All the manuals/docs show how to add the page using Facebook UI, but we need to do that using their API.

Could you guys point me to the right documentation if there is any.

THanks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/subscriptions-edge, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v9.0/app/subscriptions

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I looked at these docs but I cannot seem to find the exact API url where I can subscribe my app to some facebook page's messenger communication. I can only do that manually.
Any idea?
THanks

Comment: Are you asking about subscribing the page in the first place? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps#Creating

Comment: @CBroe Thank you very much. It needed an extra permission when the user gives us the access, but now it works like charm.
Thanks a lot for the help !